# Zoom ImageView in android like Instagram

Tags: java, android, image, zooming

How can I zoom ImageView like Instagram. I mean changing the size of imageview, not zooming the image inside the Imageview.

For zooming the image inside the Imageview, there are a lot of samples but I want something like Instagram image zooming

Any code or hint? Thanks.

Comment: I posted you an answer you might take a look at.

Comment: @anix-pasbesoin . sure, I will  test it and post the say the result here

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would recommend these two libraries:

1. [PhotoView](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView)
2. [ImageViewZoom](https://github.com/sephiroth74/ImageViewZoom)

For PhotoView, you just have to create an `attacher` and "attach" it to your `ImageView`.

#### Some code

```
// After getting your imageImage view, attach it like the following
PhotoViewAttacher yourAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(yourImageView);
```

With just this code, you'll be able to zoom in/out/whatever on `yourImageView`. Check the links above for more details.

## EDIT

Instagram has changed a lot since this answer was posted, and the libraries I recommended above might not provide the experience you are looking for.

Comment: i can used your posted libraries, but still zoom within imageview not like instagram..

Comment: @MDKhali things might have changed since I initially posted this answer.

Answer (score 17):

I recommend [Zoomy](https://github.com/imablanco/Zoomy), very simple and functional.

Just add the following to your current `ImageView`:

```java
Zoomy.Builder builder = new Zoomy.Builder(this).target(mZoomableView);
builder.register();
```

Comment: Zoomy is very nice! It supports zooming, resetting, and has callbacks for when zoom starts/ends. This is something that was missing from a few of the other libraries mentioned.

Comment: Also it's great that it allows to add interpolators https://thoughtbot.com/blog/android-interpolators-a-visual-guide

Comment: How to disable automatic zoom out

Comment: To import: `implementation 'com.ablanco.zoomy:zoomy:1.1.0'` (On GitHub the link to the latest version is dead, the latest version is `1.1.0`)

Answer (score 1):

thanks

I have added this to my gradle.build

```
 compile 'it.sephiroth.android.library.imagezoom:imagezoom:2.2.5'
```

and then using this view

```
  <it.sephiroth.android.library.imagezoom.ImageViewTouch
    android:id="@+id/mp3Image"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_width="346dp"
    android:layout_height="356dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
```

and the below code, the zoom came to my app

```
   myImage = (ImageViewTouch) findViewById(R.id.mp3Image);
    myImage.setDisplayType(ImageViewTouchBase.DisplayType.FIT_IF_BIGGER);
```