# How to implement tagging functionality like Instagram with an imageview with exact dimensions in android?

Tags: image, tagging

I am working on Tag functionality like Instagram in android,but i am not getting any proper way that how to get tag points on an image and show in another screen with exact points.

Comment: I guess you could get more help from people if you'd edit your question to be more clear, adding also what you tried so far.

Comment: Hello here is my github link please visit here i think your problem solution inside this link, hope this will help you
https://github.com/imhemantsharma/InstagramTagFeature

Comment: please check it there is another solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41795962/zoom-imageview-in-android-like-instagram

Comment: For **AndroidX** https://github.com/karanatwal/MaterialChipsInput